# Comparison operators !== against 0

Tags: javascript, comparison, equality

I think that it is obvious what my code does.

Why does my code return a whole string if I use the `!==` operator? I know that arrays in Javascript start from at index `0`, and here I'm entering the whole filename as the argument, so `indexOf(".")` will always be greater then `0`. No, I'm not passing an .htaccess file here.

```
function getFileExtension(i) {

    // return the file extension (with no period) if it has one, otherwise false
   if(i.indexOf(".") !== 0) { // 
       return i.slice(i.indexOf(".") + 1, i.length);
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

// here we go! Given a filename in a string (like 'test.jpg'),

getFileExtension('pictureofmepdf'); return given string
// both operand are same type and value
```

But if I change comparasion to

```
(i.indexOf(".") > 0) // logs false
```

P.S. I case that you are asking, this is form usvsth3m.

Comment: If i > 0, than is obvious that is also different (not equal) !== to zero (0)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you do know that 0 could be a valid index right? arrays start at 0 in javascript

Comment: This isn't really adding to any answer, but a neat trick for this particular problem is doing `return i.split('.').pop()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf()` returns the index of the substring, so it *can* return `0`, which would mean that the substring appears at position `0`. If the substring is not found, it returns `-1` instead, so change your `if` statement to reflect this logic:

```
if(i.indexOf(".") >= 0)
```

Additionally, you should use `substring()` to extract a substring from a string - `slice()` is for arrays.

```
return i.substring(i.indexOf(".") + 1, i.length);
```

Still, I think a better way to do this is with `split()`:

```
var fileNameArray = i.split("."); // "foo.txt" --> ["foo" "txt"]
if(fileNameArray.length >= 2) {
    return fileNameArray[1];
} else {
    return false; //maybe you want to return "" instead?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The String method `indexOf` returns (if it is founded) the first index of the string you search, and remember, index can be zero, that why you have to do a strict comparision to check if `indexOf` it is not returning a **boolean false**.

I will suggest you to use `lastIndexOf` for this case because a file named as `something.min.js` will return `min.js` as an valid extension, and nope.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to simplify, I omit that indexOf returns **index** which is typeof number, or **-1**, not returning boolean value FALSE in case when given value not found. So in case of comparing -1 to 0, result is true, and that's why I actually geting outputed given string, instead false. Well, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is in my bookmark bar now

```
var z = -1;
console.log(z >= 0); // evaluates false because -1 < 0
console.log(z !== 0); // evaluates true because -1 !== 0
// also if z > 0 it is !== 0, but could be < 0
```

So next code works like a charm.

```
function getFileExtension(i) {

    // i will be a string, but it may not have a file extension.
    // return the file extension (with no period) if it has one, otherwise false
   if(i.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
       return i.substring(i.indexOf(".") + 1, i.length);
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

getFileExtension('pictureofmepdf');
```